# Show PATH in a human-readable way

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

I want to show my PATH environment variable in a more human-readable way.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/arturo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/groovy/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/grails/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/griffon/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/gradle/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/lazybones/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/vertx/current/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/bin:/Users/arturo/.gvm/ext:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I'm thinking in something like this:

```
$ echo $PATH | some cut and awk magic
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/bin
...
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate https://askubuntu.com/q/600018/295286 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96334/55572

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use `tr`.

```
$ tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
...
```

You can also do this in some shells (tested in bash and zsh):

```
echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
```

In zsh, you can use the `$path` variable to see your path with spaces instead of colons.

```
$ echo $path
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin /Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin /Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin /Users/arturo/.rvm/bin
```

Which can be combined with `printf` or `print`.

```
$ printf "%s\n" $path
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
...
$ print -l $path
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin
/Users/arturo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
...
```

---

The `<<<` operators are called herestrings. Herestrings pass the word to their right to the standard input of the command on their left.

```
$ cat <<< 'Hello there'
Hello there
```

If your shell doesn't support them, use `echo` and a pipe.

```
$ echo 'Hello there' | cat
Hello there
```

Comment: Interesting the use of the here-string, I'd do the following: `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'` but is more clear your solution.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to explain the use of herestrings to any passersby.

Comment: In zsh, `print -l $path` saves a few keystrokes. It fails if `$path` contains backslashes, but that's highly unusual.

Comment: Note that some of those will fail to display the empty entries in `$PATH`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: I never thought about that. The first two display empty entries. The zsh-only ones do not.

Comment: @Gilles: For the sake of completeness, I have added that to my answer.

Comment: In bash, `echo ${PATH//:/\\n}` gives me literal `\n` sequences, not newlines. I don't use zsh, but I wonder what `printf "%s\n" $path` will do if some of the directory names contain spaces. (I just tried it, and it handles them correctly.)

Comment: Oops. For bash compatibility, that should be `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}`. I have edited my answer to fix that typo.

Comment: This would break if any directories in $PATH contain colons in their name; a somewhat solution would be `echo $PATH | tr ':/' '\n/'` -- but that would still break if a directory like `/foo:/bar` was in the $PATH...

Comment: Bash and zsh can't handle path directories with colons in their names. Take a look at the `extract_colon_unit` function in `general.c` for bash and the `colonsplit` function in `utils.c` for zsh.

Comment: `tr ':/' '\n/'` would translate `:` to `\n` and `/` to `/`, meaning it's the same as `tr ':' '\n'`. You could use sed instead: `sed 's|:/|\n/|'`.

Comment: @evilsoup "directory names that might be used in PATH should not include a <colon> character." –[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)

Comment: `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}` is problematic. With a path element of `/my\tdir` it will expand the `\t` into a TAB. With a single path element of just `/usr/bin/*` it will treat it as a glob pattern in bash unless you turn off globbing with `set -f` or `set -o noglob`. I suggest `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"`. Successfully tested in bash, zsh, and ksh93. Note: [ANSI-C quoting is not POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827) (but neither is `echo -e`). You could also replace the `$'\n'` with a literal newline.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick way with `bash`

```
OLDIFS=$IFS IFS=: arr=($PATH) IFS=$OLDIFS
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: You can avoid saving/restoring `IFS` by using a subshell. e.g. `(IFS=: arr=($PATH); printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]})")`

Comment: That will also fail to display an empty entry in most shells if it's last (`/bin:/usr/bin:` used to be a common value for `$PATH`)

Comment: In can also fail if `$PATH` contains some wildcard characters (unlikely)

Comment: As you specified `bash` anyway, you may use `IFS=: read -a arr <<< "$PATH"` for the splitting part. That way `IFS`'s new value will be used only while executing the `read`, so no need to restore it. http://pastebin.com/7E7C4AcR

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. @manatwork, do you know why `IFS`'s new value persists after array creation but not after executing `read`?

Comment: From “The environment for any _simple command_ or _function_ may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.” – [Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) and “Arrays are assigned to using _compound assignments_ of the form `name=(value1 … valuen)`” – [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)
 in the Bash Reference Manual I understand that array assignment doesn't support setting env variables that way

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Smith John's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80153/154067) solution, this makes for a nice alias in your `.bash_profile`:

```
alias MyPath='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that an unset PATH has a different meaning from an empty PATH. An empty PATH contains one empty element, and that means looking for executables in the current directory only, an unset PATH means to search for executables in a default list of directories (but note that on some systems, not every tool agrees on the content of that list)

In `zsh`:

```
if (($+PATH)); then
  echo "$#path element(s):"
  printf '%q\n' "$path[@]"
else
  echo "PATH unset"
fi
```

In POSIX shells:

```
if [ -n "${PATH+.}" ]; then
  (
    set -o noglob
    IFS=:
    set -- $PATH''
    echo "$# element(s):"
    printf '"%s"\n' "$@"
  )
else
  echo "PATH unset"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `sed` more intuitive:

```bash
$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```