# Which shells support ANSI-C quoting? e.g. $'string'

Tags: shell, quoting, escape-characters, portability

I have a shell script that uses the following to print a green checkmark in its output:

```
col_green="\e[32;01m"
col_reset="\e[39;49;00m"

echo -e "Done ${col_green}✓${col_reset}"
```

After reading about Bash's [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), I realized I could use it when setting my color variables and remove the `-e` flag from my *echo*.

```
col_green=$'\e[32;01m'
col_reset=$'\e[39;49;00m'

echo "Done ${col_green}✓${col_reset}"
```

This seems appealing, since it means the message prints correctly whether it's passed to Bash's builtin *echo* or the external util `/bin/echo` (I'm on macOS).

But does this make the script less portable? I know Bash and Zsh support this style of quoting, but I'm not sure about others.

Comment: Yes, since when only ksh and its variations support it for now. But IIRC, ANSI-C quoting is going to be in next POSIX spec.

Comment: ksh doc: [debian ksh(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ksh/ksh.1.en.html#Quoting.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$'…'` is a ksh93 feature that is also present in zsh, bash, mksh, FreeBSD sh and in some builds of BusyBox sh (BusyBox ash built with `ENABLE_ASH_BASH_COMPAT`). It isn't present in the POSIX sh language yet. Common Bourne-like shells that don't have it include dash (which is `/bin/sh` by default on Ubuntu among others), ksh88, the Bourne shell, NetBSD sh, yash, derivatives of pdksh other than mksh and some builds of BusyBox.

A portable way to get backslash-letter and backslash-octal parsed as control characters is to use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html). It's present on all POSIX-compliant systems.

```
esc=$(printf '\033') # assuming an ASCII (as opposed to EBCDIC) system
col_green="${esc}[32;01m"
```

Note that `\e` is not portable. It's supported by many implementations of `printf` but not by the one in dash¹. Use the octal code instead.

¹  <sub>It is supported in Debian and derivatives that ship at least 0.5.8-2.4, e.g. since Debian stretch and Ubuntu 17.04.</sub>

Comment: are you sure about `\e` not being supported in `dash`? `dash -c 'printf "\e[1;31m"; type printf; printf "\e[m"'` will print `printf is a shell builtin` in bold red here (dash-0.5.8). A shell that doesn't support `\e` is  `yash`.

Comment: @mosvy Prints `\e[1;31mprintf is a shell builtin
\e[m` here. Ubuntu 16.04, dash 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2. Prints in red on Ubuntu 18.04 with dash 0.5.8-2.10. Looks like Ubuntu made a patch to support it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it looks that's a debian (9.7 stretch) patch. [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/dash@vger.kernel.org/msg01722.html)'s the original.

Answer (score 0):

The degree of `$'...'` support also needs to be taken into consideration when porting. The [POSIX Folks' proposal to put this in POSIX sh](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249) mentions one in particular:

> stephane: ksh93 is the shell $'...' comes from (while `$'\uxxxx'` [*and `$'\Uxxxxxxxx'`*] comes from zsh: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2003/msg00223.html) [^]

From what I got here on my Debian bullseye, the `ksh2020` understands `$'\U1F600'`. This is the only "official" Korn shell I can get on this new distro.

`mksh` parsed it but botched it entirely with a U+FFFE. Since it did not complain about a syntax error there's gotta be something wrong with it's understanding of Unicode. It handles `$'\U01F60'` just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, as an effect of a recent [coup](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/1466) ksh2020 has been disappeared. But yes, the original ksh93 does support `$'...'` and iirc it was the first who did.

Comment: @Arthur2e5. `ksh2020` is not from AT&T. A couple of people, one from Red Hat, essentially hijacked the AT&T AST github tree a few years ago and claimed control of  future `ksh93` development