# Text color using $'...', $"...", '...', and "..."

Tags: linux, bash, shell, colors, macos

For as long as I can remember, I've personally used the following method for changing the color of output text when using bash:

```bash
red=$'\033[1;31m'                                                                        
nc=$'\033[0m'

echo "${red}This is red text$nc"
```

It's always worked for me no matter if used on macOS or Linux. Out of curiosity, to better understand why it works, I've done a bit of research and have found some answers/examples that don't include `$` (`red='\033[1;31m'`). After some testing, if I don't use `$`, the output color doesn't change to red, rather it just prints the string. Though, when executing it using `sh` instead of `bash`, the text does change color. Can someone help me understand why this is?

I've additionally tested it with double quotes instead of single quotes, and it only seems to work when using `sh`. I'll post examples below.

This is the script and code I used:

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                                              
                                                                                         
red=$'\033[1;31m'                                                                        
nc=$'\033[0m'                                                                            
                                                                                         
echo "${red}Test 1$nc"                                                                   
echo ""                                                                                  
                                                                                         
##########################                                                               
                                                                                         
red=$"\033[1;31m"                                                                        
nc=$"\033[0m"                                                                            
                                                                                         
echo "${red}Test 2$nc"                                                                   
echo ""                                                                                  
                                                                                         
##########################                                                               
                                                                                         
red='\033[1;31m'                                                                         
nc='\033[0m'                                                                             
                                                                                         
echo "${red}Test 3$nc"                                                                   
echo ""                                                                                  
                                                                                         
##########################                                                               
                                                                                         
red="\033[1;31m"                                                                         
nc="\033[0m"                                                                             
                                                                                         
echo "${red}Test 4$nc"                                                                   
echo ""
```

Output on macOS with both bash and sh:

[image]

Output on Linux with both bash and sh:

[image]

Comment: Regardless of your quoting issues, you really shouldn't be outputting terminal-specific escape codes if your `TERM` isn't one of the ones that accepts those codes (or if your output is going to a non-terminal destination such as a pipe).  The portable way is `red=$(tput setaf 1)`.  That will produce the empty string when used on a dumb terminal, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main thing here is that for the terminal to recognize the control sequence, the output sent the terminal must contain the ESC character, then `[1;31m`. That ESC is a control character, and we don't usually present it as-is in a shell script, but instead we use the backslash escape `\033` to represent that character using its octal character code (it's 27 decimal, 033 octal, or 0x1b hex). The rest are just regular characters.

Now, that backslash-escape needs to be changed to the raw ESC character at some point. And there's two places where this could happen: the assignment to the variable and the command that prints it.

---

In shells that support it, the `$'...'` type of quotes interpret the escape already, so after `red=$'\033[...'`, the variable itself contains the raw ESC character. That's not a standard POSIX feature, and in shells that don't support it, that would assign the raw dollar sign, then backslash, `033[` and so on. On the other hand,  `red='\033[...'` would just assign backslash, `033[` etc., never interpreting the escape. See

- [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th) and
- [Which shells support ANSI-C quoting? e.g. $'string'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/which-shells-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string)

<sub>(`$"..."`, and `"..."` never interpret the escape, and the one with the dollar is also non-standard so might leave the literal dollar sign in shells not supporting it.)</sub>

---

Then, the second step is the printing. In some shells `echo` expands backslash escapes. In others it doesn't. Some of those have `echo -e` that again does. Bash's `echo` by default doesn't do it, but with the `xpg_echo` setting set... it does. Zsh's `echo` does interpret them. See

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

---

So, in a usual Bash on your usual Linux desktop distribution, where `xpg_echo` isn't set, `red=$'\033[1;31m'; echo "${red}text"` produces the ESC on the assignment and prints red text, but `red='\033[1;31m'; echo "${red}text"` doesn't produce it in either the assignment or the `echo` and just prints `\033[1;31mtext` in normal color.

On Debian/Ubuntu, `sh` is Dash, where the `$'...'` quotes aren't supported but `echo` does interpret backslashes, so  `red=$'\033[1;31m'; echo "${red}text"` prints a normal-colored `$`, and then the red text. This is what your run with `sh` and Linux looks like. You might get a different result in some other Linux system.

And on a Mac, the shell installed as `sh` is actually either Bash with `xpg_echo` set (the one installed as `bash` has it disabled),
or zsh in newer macOS releases.
Even though starting either as `sh` tries to make them more POSIX-compatible, *they still support* the `$'...'` quotes, so both `red=$'\033[1;31m'; echo "${red}text"` and `red='\033[1;31m'; echo "${red}text"` print red text.

---

Confused yet? `red='\033[1;31m'; printf "%b\n" "${red}text";` should work in all POSIX-like shells. The `%b` tells it to process backslash escapes in the argument, so any in "text" would get processed.

Comment: In the closing, we might want to use `printf '%b\n' "${red}text"` so any `%` sequences in the text don't try to be interpreted.

Comment: On current `macOS`:
`$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, or `printf "${red}%s\n" "text"` if we didn't want to expand backslashes in "text". No way to get this _really_ simple in the do what I want this time sense...

Comment: @DavidCowden, oh, right! Remind me, do they have zsh as `sh` too? Or just as the default interactive shell, and something else as `sh`? Looks like zsh's sh-mode still works the same, i.e. it supports `$'...'`.

Comment: @ilkkachu I also found that if I replaced `echo` with `printf` in all the tests, it printed out red text. I didn't even have to include `%b`, just straight `red='\033[1;31m'; printf "${red}text";`. I'm assuming that's because `printf` by default interprets back slashes.

Comment: @StrangeRanger, yes, it does, and it doing that in the sameway everywhere is what makes it better than `echo`. But printf also interprets percent-signs as conversion specifiers, meaning fields to fill. E.g. `value is %d` would mean to print those two words and then look in the arguments for an integer number to print. If your text contains percent signs that should print as-is, it wouldn't work. E.g. `printf "${red}value is over 90 %!"` would give an error since `%!` is an invalid specifier. You'd need to use `%%` for a single `%` instead. Passing the text through `%b`/`%s` avoids that.

Comment: @ilkkachu I see. Thank you for the help and detailed explanation!

Comment: So to complete that example I showed, one could use `printf "${red}value is over %d%%!\n" "$pct"` to print that percentage. But with shell variables being strings already, the conversion isn't that necessary and `printf "${red}value is over ${pct}%%\n"`, or `printf "%b\n" "${red}value is over ${pct}%"` would work too. Also strings given with `%b` do process backslashes, strings given with `%s` _don't_, so you could use the latter for any parts of the message that might contain those.

Comment: `echo $'\302\2331;31mred\302\2330m'` works too, actually (at least in some UTF-8-based terminals)

Comment: @toby, Thanks for pointing out the error with "its". But, I wrote "using the octal character code" on purpose, since that's what the backslash escape takes. The hex escape `\x1b` works in a lot of shells, but e.g. not in Dash, and the decimal can't be used in those in any system I know.

Comment: Ah yes - sorry for screwing that up - I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer for Linux. and I think the crucial point is not how to use the ANSI escape sequences, but how to declare a variable.

```
red=$'\033[1;31m'  # a dollar sign and an ANSI escape sequence

red=$"\033[1;31m"  # a dollar sign and an ANSI escape sequence

red='\033[1;31m'  # only an ANSI escape sequence

red="\033[1;31m"  # only an ANSI escape sequence
```

In `sh`, when you print with

```
echo "${red}some text"
```

you print the value of the variable `red` and then some text. In the first two cases there is a dollar sign before the ANSI escape sequence, so it is not affected by the colour change.

In `bash`, when you print with

```
echo -e "${red}some text"
```

the ANSI escape sequence is interpreted, but with

```
echo "${red}some text"
```

the ANSI escape sequence is not interpreted, instead the characters are printed literally, but might be converted 'before' the `echo` statement.

In your `sh` there is another built-in function `echo` which obviously interprets the ANSI escape sequence without the option `-e`.

The difference for you in `bash` between the first and other examples can be explained if you look at the hexadecimal value of `red`. See my edited script,

```
#!/bin/bash

red=$'\033[1;31m'
nc=$'\033[0m'
hexdump <<< "$red"
echo $1 "${red}Test 1$nc"
echo ""

##########################

red=$"\033[1;31m"
nc=$"\033[0m"
hexdump <<< "$red"
echo $1 "${red}Test 2$nc"
echo ""

##########################

red='\033[1;31m'
nc='\033[0m'
hexdump <<< "$red"
echo $1 "${red}Test 3$nc"
echo ""

##########################

red="\033[1;31m"
nc="\033[0m"
hexdump <<< "$red"
echo $1 "${red}Test 4$nc"
echo ""
```

where I also made it convenient to look at `echo -e` by adding that option to the script, so try both

```
bash box2
```

and

```
bash box2 -e
```

---

I suggest that you declare your 'colouring' variables without any dollar sign, for example

```
red='\033[1;31m'
```

and use the dollar sign only when you *use* a variable for example in an `echo` statement.

Comment: Note that for `bash` whether its builtin `echo` expands expands escape sequences by default is controlled by the `xpg_echo` option (which will be enabled by default for builds of `bash` intended to provide a UNIX compliant environment like for the sh of macos or the bash of Solaris 11+)

Comment: Thanks for this important information :-) Please edit my answer, if you wish.

Comment: Note that it's all covered in [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: that one and [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th). The difference between `red=$'\033[1;31m'` and `red='\033[1;31m'` is that the former puts the ESC char in the variable already ([in shells that support it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/which-shells-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string)), and the latter leaves the backslash sequence there, waiting for `echo` or something else to interpret it.