How to highlight the matched regex pattern got by many regex exps disjoined with `||` in awk?
This highlight feature can be done easily in grep with --color. But grep can't do regular and invert match at the same time, e.g. grep foo -v bar ... (I need this feature since --color can be only used at the initial input of the pipe |, so the latter grep will use that colored results which make grep foo --color=always ... | grep -v "foo bar" won't remove those lines with "foo bar").
So I used awk as the above link hints but it lacks highlight feature. We can extract the  regex results with match and substr where we wrap the regex pattern in match like /\<no issue\>/. We can then highlight only the regex result with ANSI color codes by printf substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "\033[1;31m" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) "\033[0m: " substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) "\n".
Q:
But match doesn't work for the boolean expr /foo/ && !/bar/ constructed by regex exp's in the reference link. Is there one elegant workaround (maybe with other tools)?
I thought about one temporary workaround /foo/ && !/bar/{match($0,/foo/); printf ...} but that will do regex twice.
My expected behavior (Here 0. "TODO" can exist at most once in one line 1. I use *...* to show what to be highlighted 2. I only consider /pattern1/ && !/pattern_included_totally_by_pattern1/, so /foo/ && !/o/ offered by Ed Morton is not considered. This is just like grep logic that I first grep some and then grep in those results got from the former grep execution):
# fail
$ echo "TODO foo\nTODO" | grep TODO --color=always | grep -v "TODO foo"
*TODO* foo
*TODO*
# expected
$ echo "TODO foo\nTODO" | awk -v RED="\033[1;31m" -v RESET="\033[0m" '/TODO/ && !/TODO foo/ {match($0,/TODO/); printf substr($0,1,RSTART-1) RED substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) RESET substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) "\n"}'
*TODO*


What do you want to highlight if the match on !/\<issue\>/ succeeds? The whole line?

@meuh Sorry. I had one typo. Actually I used && which is different from the reference link. So that compound regex exp should be viewed as one whole object.

Can't you just swap the commands? grep -v 'foo bar' | grep --color=always foo

It's not clear from your question and comments what it is you're trying to do. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your needs and we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with so we can best help you. Just use text like RED, GREEN, RESET in your example instead of color escape sequences for clarity and simplicity - you can change that part on your own later.

@Kusalananda Thanks. I know what I was wrong for grep now. I originally also tried to grep  foo | grep --color=always -v 'foo bar' but that has no color. That is due to --color only color matched words, so not for "invert-match" words.

@EdMorton Thanks. I added one simple sample demonstration.

Your workaround is perfectly acceptable. Note, since you seem to be using
gnu awk, you can also use sub() or
gsub() to substitute a regexp by a string, with & being replaced by the
matched part:
/foo/ && !/bar/ {
  sub(/foo/, "\033[1;31m" "&" "\033[0m: ")  # changes $0
  print
}

If you don't want to repeat the regexp you can split the tests up
!/bar/{ if(/foo/){ sub(...); print } }

or since sub() returns 1 on success
!/bar/{ if(sub(/foo/, ...)) print }

or
!/bar/ && sub(/foo/, ...) { print }


sub() and gsub() will work in any awk, it's gensub() that'll only work in GNU awk (and 1 or 2 others).

Thanks. I use the solution in your last line since that has almost the same structure as the original. Anyway the ideas are similar among your solutions.


Here sub is same as match to return the "leftmost" substring. Anyway this is enough for my situation since my search pattern "TODO" can at most exist once in one line. 1.a. So maybe Kusalananda's workaround is better and more general (similar for Stéphane Chazelas's). But anyway this answer replies to my question about awk more appropriately.


Complement for 1: gsub mentioned by Ed Morton will work for the case where "TODO" occurs more than once which is explicitly shown by the edit of Stéphane Chazelas's answer.

I'd use perl here. To highlight foo on lines that don't contain foo bar:
perl -pe 's/foo/\e[31;1m$&\e[m/g unless /foo bar/' < your-file

Same as:
awk '! /foo bar/ {gsub(/foo/, "\33[1;31m&\33[m")}; {print}' < your-file

Or (assuming a shell with support for ksh93-style $'...' form of quotes):
sed $'/foo bar/! s/foo/\e[1;31m&\e[m/g' < your-file

Or to highlight the foos that are not followed by  bar.
perl -pe 's/foo(?! bar)/\e[31;1m$&\e[m/g' < your-file

No awk, sed equivalent except if your sed is one of those few that support perl regexps as some do with -P (like ast-open's) or -R (like ssed)), however it's more common for grep implementations to support perl-like regexps generally with a -P option, like GNU grep does when built with perl-like regexp support via the PCRE2 library (formerly PCRE), in which case you can do:
grep -P --color 'foo(?! bar)' < your-file

But that also discards lines with no match.
To discard the lines that contain foo bar and highlight occurrences of foo in remaining lines, you could do:
perl -ne 'unless (/foo bar/) {
            s/foo/\e[31;1m$&\e[m/g;
            print
          }' < your-file

Or:
awk '! /foo bar/ {gsub(/foo/, "\33[1;31m&\33[m"); print}' < your-file

Or (assuming a shell with support for ksh93-style $'...' form of quotes):
sed  $'/foo bar/d; s/foo/\e[1;31m&\e[m/g' < your-file

But you could also do:
< your-file grep -v 'foo bar' |
  grep --color -e '^' -e foo

(-e '^' to match all lines, so they're not discarded, -e foo to highlight foo occurrences in those lines; < file.in A | B > file.out is like A < file.in | B > file.out or A < file.in | > file.out B as redirections can appear anywhere on the command lines, but using the former in pipelines is common as it makes the flow more evident).
To discard all the lines that contain foo bar and all that don't contain foo and highlight foo in the remaining ones:
perl -ne 'print if ! /foo bar/ && s/foo/\e[1;31m$&\e[m/g' < your-file

sed -n $'/foo bar/! s/foo/\e[1;31m&\e[m/gp' < your-file

awk '! /foo bar/ && gsub(/foo/, "\33[1;31m&\33[m")' < your-file

< your-file grep -v 'foo bar' | grep --color foo

Details about the perl syntax:

perl -p is the sed mode (and perl -n the sed -n mode) where the code (here supplied as an inline -expression like in sed) is run for each line of the input with the current line in $_ (equivalent of sed's pattern space with that difference that in perl, $_ does contain the line delimiter). See perldoc perlrun for details.
s/replacement/replacement/ is similar to sed's but with many improvements, in particular much more feature-full regexps, that many other languages have copied since.
(?! foo) is one of those extra regexp operators introduced by perl, which is a negative look ahead operator. See perldoc perlre for details.
code unless some-condition is a short form of unless (some-condition) {code} which reads more like English but is otherwise equivalent. unless being like if !. See perldoc perlsyn for details.


Thanks anyway although normally I don't use perl.

Some references for someone unfamiliar with perl same as me: 1. -p https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/one-liner-introduction.html#substitution seems to ensure outputting the results "$_ is automatically printed". 2. options like -e: see man perlrun 3. $&: man perlretut 4. unless: man perlsyn

The perl doc is really large and I haven't learnt about that language before. One small question: Is there one way to avoid outputting the lines like foo bar?

@An5Drama, see edit.

Thanks so much for the so detailed edit. Small questions:  1. Is -e '^' in grep --color -e '^' -e foo necessary? IMHO that just grep those lines with the beginning "empty string" and different -es doesn't influence with each other as man says. 2. IMHO "To discard all the lines that contain foo bar and all that don't contain foo and highlight foo in the remaining ones:" is same as "To discard the lines that contain foo bar and highlight occurrences of foo in remaining lines," since if ! a && b is same as unless a{b} based on short circuit of && for perl (Continued)

which is also said by your last paragraph. Similarly sed -n doesn't print by default as perl -n and we use p modifier, so still same (Similar for the rest). Is it that case?

Some references for the edit:  1. $'...': https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/568529. 2. ast-open's sed: https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/lib/package/ast-open.README 3. < used at the beginning of line: https://superuser.com/a/843143/1658455 where < influences the command before control operator |

@An5Drama see edit. To see the differences between the various commands, you can check on the output of printf '%s\n' foo 'foo bar' 'foo foo bar' 'bar foo' bar as it's not clear in your question whether you want to just highlight some foos or also discard the lines without foo or with foo bar (and whether or not they also contain foo not followed by  bar).

Thanks. With that printf demo, I also found that ?! seems to consume checked string, so 'foo(?! bar)' won't filter out "foo foo bar". This seems to be implied implicitly by python re doc https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430936/21294350 and also in man perlre "the lookaheads are zero-width expressions--they only look, but don't consume any of the string".

@An5Drama, no you've got it backward, (?!...) (not !? which without the (...) just matches 0 or 1 !) looks ahead, it doesn't consume. It correctly matches on the first foo because it's not followed by  bar and correctly does not match on the second because it is followed by  bar . Thanks to the fact it does not consume input, it would correctly match on the first two occurrences of foo in the output of echo foo foo foo bar.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

At times in your question it sounds like you want to highlight a whole line that satisfies the condition /foo/ && !/bar/ which is just (replace RED and RESET with color codes as you like):
awk '/foo/ && !/bar/ { print "RED" $0 "RESET" }'

while at other times it sounds like you want to highlight lines that match foo but not foo bar which would be:
awk '/foo/ && !/foo bar/ { print "RED" $0 "RESET" }'

or to avoid writing foo twice:
awk 'match($0,/foo/) && (substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) !~ / bar/) {
    print "RED" $0 "RESET"
}'

while at other times still it sounds like you only want to highlight the part that matches foo on a line that does not contain bar which is just:
awk '!/bar/ && match($0,/foo/) {
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "RED" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) "RESET" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}'

If you want something different than either of those then show an example in your question. In particular, if you're looking for a general solution that can highlight parts of lines given multiple regexps in a compound condition, explain in your question the logic behind what to highlight and what not to highlight, including for the case /foo/ && !/o/.


Sorry for my inconsistency. I added one sample demonstration. You can just use that and ignore those inconsistency. Anyway, I want to emphasize && can't be used directly in match. If !/bar/ or !/foo bar/ confused you, sorry for that. 2. "at other times still it sounds like you only want to highlight the part": Actually I just want the  behavior same as grep, i.e. only highlighting the matched pattern. Sorry for not saying that explicitly.


Regarding "&& can't be used directly in match" - right, there's no && in regexps and the 2nd arg to match() is a regexp, not a compound condition. Regarding "I just want the behavior same as grep" - it's not obvious exactly what that statement means but I'm glad you got an answer you're happy with.
